# search hierarchical list in R

Tags: r, data-management

I have a long list of variable labels produced by the `var_label` function in the `labelled` packages which looks like this:

```
list(prtclcie = "Which party feel closer to, Ireland", dweight = "Design weight", 
    edlvfdit = "Father's highest level of education, Italy", 
    edlvpdru = "Partner's highest level of education, Russian Federation", 
    edlvdpt = "Highest level of education, Portugal", icwhct = "Have a set 'basic' or contracted number of hours", 
    uemp3m = "Ever unemployed and seeking work for a period more than three months", 
    icomdng = "Interviewer code, one/more than one doing last 7 days", 
    edlvfenl = "Father's highest level of education, Netherlands", 
    prtvtdfi = "Party voted for in last national election, Finland")
```

I would like to find a command to search this list based on keywords, in a way that the output is the column name, stg. like `prtclcie`, `edlvfdit` and alike.

I have tried with `grep("keyword", list)`, but this only gives the row number of the "hit", not the upper level name in the list structure.

Answer (score 1):

Use `value=TRUE` to return the values rather than just the index

```
grep("educ", list, value=TRUE)
```

If you just want the name from the list, use

```
names(grep("educ", list, value=TRUE))
```